# How to automatically create subfolders in document library folders?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I use a Microsoft Sharepoint 2010 document library to manage documents in Microsoft CRM 2011. CRM can automatically create folders in a Sharepoint document library when user creates an entity like Opportuniny. So far so good, but I want to automatically create some subfolders in the folder created by the CRM. The subfolders are the same for all Opportuninties.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as custom code is an option, you could use an event receiver on the ItemAdded event for the list - by making use of the [SPListItem.Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.folder.aspx) property you could check to see if the item is a folder and, if so, create sub-folders for it.

However, this gets trickier since the same ItemAdded event will fire when you add those sub-folders too - you'll have to do something like check the URL of the folder to see where it is within the library's folder structure.